# Exception instead of null when reading a resource in Groovy

Tags: groovy, resources

Right now to safely acquire `text` from resource file (proper exception instead of NPE) I need to use the following snippet of code:

```
String resourceText(String resourcePath) {
    URL resource = this.getClass().getResource(resourcePath)
    if (!resource) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No file at $resourcePath")
    }
    resource.text
}
```

Is there any library that already does exactly that? It looks like resources should always be accessed in such `null`-safe way.

Comment: Why not: `resource?.text` or `Optional.ofNullable(resource)`?

Comment: I've found a better way by myself, I'll respond now. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid NPE you can use [safe navigation operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator), the return value will be evaluated to null:

```
String resourceText(String resourcePath) {
    URL resource = this.getClass().getResource(resourcePath)
    resource?.text
}
```

Much better option is to use optionals:

```
String resourceText(String resourcePath) {
    URL resource = this.getClass().getResource(resourcePath)
    Optional.ofNullable(resource).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No file at $resourcePath")).text
}
```

Comment: The first snippet is exactly what I want to avoid (I don't want to return null), while the second is nice, but not much shorter and uses Java 8 features. Would be nice to have something for Java 7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using Guava the method can be much shorter:

```
String resourceText(String resourcePath) {
    Resources.getResource(this.class, resourcePath).text
}
```

From its Javadoc:

> `@throws IllegalArgumentException if the resource is not found`

Comment: Guava under the hood does exactly the same! It seems pointless to add a whole dependency just even not to substitute 5 lines of code.

Comment: Sure, but in majority of projects I work with Guava is added anyway. Also, these 5 lines of code duplicated dozens of times across the project would probably beg for extracting to a separate class/util (at least to have error message unified) and you would need to do it separately for each project. By using Guava you can have unified way of accessing resources across all projects you work on without much thinking.